# How can I get the install state of Safari iOS extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, safari-extension

I'd like to know the install state of my iOS safari extension in the associated swift app. Is there any way to get this?

`SFSafariExtensionManager` and `getStateOfSafariExtension` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionmanager) only seems valid on macOS safari extensions. Is there any equivalent method for iOS?

Comment: Are you able to find it? @tob88